# Kendo UI Bar Chart - MajorTicks Placement

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

The default placement of the Majorticks on the category axis of the Kendo UI Bar/Column Chart is a bit confusing. Even with the samples (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/overview) you notice that for a single column per category, tick marks do not align above the labels, but to the right of the column. Most other charting packages align the column, the tick and the label in one vertical position.

Is there any setting that can align the column, above the MajorTicks and the labels for each (date) category?